# Setup element getter for dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

This works, according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> inventory = [('apple', 3), ('banana', 2), ('pear', 5), ('orange', 1)]
>>> list(map(operator.itemgetter(1), inventory))
[3, 2, 5, 1]
```

Now I want to do something similar, for a list of dicts:

```
>>> data = [{'xxx': 'x'}, {'xxx': 'y'}]
>>> list(map(operator.attrgetter('xxx'), data))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'xxx'
```

I was expecting:

```
['x', 'y']
```

But it seems `attrgetter` does not work for dictionaries (only for classes?). How can I setup an "element getter" for dictionaries?

Comment: `xxx` is not an attribute of the dictionaries you are showing.

Comment: @Chris_Rands I want to use map

Comment: @Anthon indeed, as stated by the error message

Answer (score 2):

Well, the **item** you want to get is `'xxx'`. (In both cases, you want to call the object's `__getitem__` method for each object in the list.)

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> data = [{'xxx': 'x'}, {'xxx': 'y'}]
>>> map(itemgetter('xxx'), data)
['x', 'y']
```

Think of attributes as anything you access via the dot notation, i.e. `mydict.xxx` in your case. You should see why that fails.

Comment: Strange that the documentation for itemgetter only shows examples for access of list or tuples elements, that is, for integer indexes

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [timgeb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43716803/2063361), you should be calling [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) with the key (because [`attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) are used to get the class attribute which are accessible by `.` like `class_obj.<attribute>`).

In order to achieve your desired result, usage of *list comprehension* is a easier approach:

```
>>> data = [{'xxx': 'x'}, {'xxx': 'y'}]
>>> [d['xxx'] for d in data]
['x', 'y']
```

Also, please note that `map` since python 3.x returns a *generator* object instead of a `list` object.