# 'str' object has no attribute 'match_key' when sorting dictionary

Tags: python, django, django-views

Full error: `'str' object has no attribute 'match_key'`

I am trying to sort a dictionary by the values of one of the keys in the objects but I am running into errors whem doing so. What is the best way to do this kind of sort?

Code:

```
#part of loop

x = {
    'id': f'{item.id}',
    'post': item,
    'match_key': match_percentage

}

temp_dict.update(x)

sorted_dict = sorted(temp_dict, key=operator.attrgetter('match_key'))
```

Comment: Are you actually trying to sort a list of dictionaries, using a particular key?  Because it doesn't make sense to sort a single dictionary by a single key.

Comment: `sorted_dict = sorted(temp_dict, key=operator.attrgetter(temp_dict['match_key]'))`

Comment: im looping to create multiple objects in the dict so yes there will be a lot of objects to sort through @TimNyborg

Comment: @Ajay when i do that i get error: `attribute name must be a string`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value

Comment: looks like there is a quotes ( ' ' ) mismatch in @Ajay's answer..   sorted_dict = sorted(temp_dict, key=operator.attrgetter(temp_dict['match_key']))

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to sort a list of dictionaries by key, you'll want to use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) instead like this:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

xs = [
    { 'item': "Apple", 'match_key': 20 },
    { 'item': "Grape", 'match_key': 10 },
    { 'item': "Lemon", 'match_key': 50 }]

sorted_dict = sorted(xs, key=itemgetter('match_key'))

print(sorted_dict)
# [{'item': 'Grape', 'match_key': 10},
#  {'item': 'Apple', 'match_key': 20}, 
#  {'item': 'Lemon', 'match_key': 50}]
```

#### Explanation

[`dictionaries`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) represent collections of items. So values stored in dictionaries are considered `items`, not `attributes`.  This makes sense when we think about how we access values in dictionaries. You use *bracket notation* `[]` to access items in a collection, whether by index position or key.  But cannot use the *dot operator* `.` to retrieve dictionary values by key, because they are not stored as attributes on the dict.

#### Further Reading

- [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72899/1366033)
- [Sorting a list of dictionary values by date in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/652291/1366033)
- [Setup element getter for dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43716777/1366033)